# Confusion about open and closed sets in metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(X,T)$ be the induced topology.
I understand that $$B_r(a) = \{x: x \in X \land d(a,x) < r\}$$ is open in $(X,d)$ because it is open in $(X,T)$.
I'm trying to show that $D_{r_{1}}(b) = \{x: x \in X \land d(b,x) \le r_1\}$ is closed in $(X,d)$, or equivalently $X$ \ $D_{r_{1}}(b)= D^{c}_{r_{1}}(b) = \{x: x \in X \land d(b,x) > r_1\}$ is open in $(X,d)$.

I can't figure out how to show this.

Comment: See Theorem 5.9 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/metricspaces.pdf

Comment: Draw a picture of $D_{r_1}(b)$. Pick aribitrary element outside the disk. Try to figure out how big you need to make a ball around $b$ so the ball doesn't intersect the disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in wanting to show the complement of $D_{r_1}(b)$is open.  Let $p \in X\setminus D_{r_1}(b) = D_{r_1}^c(b)$, and consider the distance $d(b,p)$.  We would like to show that there is a ball around $p$ contained in $D_{r_1}^c(b)$, and this boils down to picking a radius small enough.  Note that $r_2 = d(b,p) - r_1$ is the distance from $p$ to the outer edge of $D_{r_1}(b)$.  Now, for the sake of picking a more comfortable distance, let $r = \frac{r_2}{2}$.  Let $q \in B_r(p)$, and show that $q \in D_{r_1}^c(b)$ using the triangle inequality.

Comment: How would I show that $q$ is an element of $D^{c}_{r_{1}}(b)$ using the triangle inequality?

I know that if $q \in B_r(p)$ then $d(q,p) < \frac{d(b,p) - r_1}{2}$.  So I need to show that $d(q,b) > r_1$.  I figure I need a chain of inequalities but I can't figure one out.

Comment: @OliverG Observe that $d(b,p) \leq d(b,q) + d(q,p) < d(b,q)  + r$, and further this inequality by noting how $r$ is defined above.

Comment: $d(q,p) < \frac{d(b,p) - r_1}{2} \le d(b,p) -r_1 \Rightarrow r_1 < d(q,p) - d(b,p)$ and

$r_1 = |r_1| < |d(b,p) - d(q,p) | \le d(b,q)$.

Does that sound right?

Comment: @OliverG I think you want to write one of your inequalities as $r_1 < d(b,p) - d(q,p)$, but this doesn't really show you want to prove.  You want to demonstrate that $d(b,q) > r_1$.  It's not exactly clear to me how your second inequality works either.

Comment: My mistake on switching the signs incorrectly for the first part.  The second inequality is the reverse triangle inequality

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reverse_Triangle_Inequality

Comment: $r_1 < d(b,p) - d(q,p)$ and by the reverse triangle inequality $|d(b,p) - d(q,p)| \le d(b,q)$, therefore $|r_1| < |d(b,p) - d(q,p)| \le d(b,q)$ $\Rightarrow$ $r_1 < d(b,q)$.

Comment: @OliverG That seems reasonable.  I was going for a different approach with the triangle inequality.  Namely $d(b,p) < d(b,q) + r <  d(b,q) + d(b,p) - r_1$.